# Optimize the use of Git to manage projects related with a common origin and repository

Tags: git, project, project-structure

This is my current situation:

I am developing an online course platform in PHP.

The core of the platform is in a server folder called `platform`.
The frontend of each course (html, javascript, images, etc ...) is in its own folder, for example: `www.curso1.com`, `www.curso2.com`, etc ... and have an `include` of the core of the platform.
Each course has its own front-end elements, but also templates that are similar to each other courses.

Current git configuration:
The core is managed with a Git repository called `platform` with its branches `develop` and `master`.
All the courses front-end are in a Git repository called `courses`, but, for each one, I have created a branch `course1/develop`, `course1/master`, `course2/develop`, `course2/master`, etc..

**Issue:**
There is a folder (`Templates`) in the courses that contains templates that adapt slightly to each course but most of the code is shared among them.
When I fix small errors in a template, I fix them on a new branche `course1/fixtemplatebug` of `course1/develop` and I make a merge with `course1/develop` and/or `course1/master`. But I have to propagate those changes manually in the other courses using some 'diff' tool like WinMerge or similar.

**Question:**
Since all the courses have a common repository, using Git: Is there any way to propagate those 'fixes' to each course without losing the adaptations of each course in their templates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest thing to do here might be to just fix minor template errors in the parent `developer` or `master` branch in your `platform` repo.  Then, rebase or merge each course feature branch on this single parent branch.  This way, you only need to make a single commit to fix the template problem.  You should would have to do legwork to bring that change into the course branches.  But you should expect to have to do some work to fix a bug.

Comment: `template` code is not on `platform` repo, but on `courses` repo. If I fix one error and commit to `course1/develop`, I can't rebase `course1/develop` branch on `course2/develop` because they are a lot of code on another files that it's very different.

Comment: So you're saying that not all your code is on a single repository?  That's probably bad design, at least for something as simple as you're doing.  I'll delete this once you reply.

Comment: I have two repos: One repo with php code (`platform`) that contains the common core of all projects, and another repo (`courses`) that contains html, css, etc.. for each course, with one branche (`course1/develop`, `course2/develop`) for each course code. Because each course have his own html pages, but only a few (`templates` folder) similary pages.

Comment: Stop doing that.  If the code in both repos _ever_ needs to talk with each other, via updates, merges, etc., then use a _single_ repo, not two of them.

Comment: Ok, thanks for for the advice. I will take it. But, assume I have only one repo: `courses`. And I made changes on brach `course1/develop` that I want to propagate to anothers branches: `course2/develop`, `course3/develop` that have a lot of changes and different commits versus `course1/develop`. They are one easy way to do it with Git?

Comment: Yes, the answer I gave above.

Comment: Thanks, the first time I did not understand your answer correctly. You are talking about make 'fixes' on root `develop` branch of my repo. And later rebase `develop/course1`, `develop/course2`, etc... It is?

Comment: Something like that.

Comment: I can't rebase develop onto `develop/course1`, etc.. because I have a lot of merged commits and I will lost info. Even using `preservemerge` flag, I think it is not very safe to rebase on branches with merges

Comment: Agreed.  Then maybe merging is your best option.